# Disable simple fan from Spring Boot (Gradle)

Tags: oracle, spring-boot

I try to disabled `simplefan` from Gradle but without positive results.
My `build.gradle` contains this:

```
runtimeOnly ('com.oracle.database.jdbc:ojdbc8-production:19.7.0.0') {
    exclude group: "com.oracle.ojdbc", module: "simplefan"
    exclude group: "com.oracle.jdbc", module: "ons"     
}
```

Now the Spring Boot app shows  `ERROR 14444 --- [ORKER-THREAD-34] oracle.simplefan.FanManager`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I get the solution: the problem is in the dependencies of Oracle a Java Compatiblity. I have:

```
sourceCompatibility=8
```

and

```
runtimeOnly 'com.oracle.database.jdbc:ojdbc8-production:19.7.0.0'   com.oracle.database.jdbc:ojdbc8-production:19.7.0.0
```

replace above with:

```
com.oracle.database.jdbc:ojdbc8:21.5.0.0
```

Solved my problem message. Thanks :D